# Is there a way to measure the size of a web service response?

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a .NET desktop client application which references some .NET web services. I'd like to see the size of the responses the client application is receiving. Is there a way to do this? I've tried using Wireshark, but I can't see packets when the host and destination are both localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) allows you to see and debug all HTTP traffic, also on localhost. You might need to [setup proxy for localhost in the system.net configuration section](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET).

Answer (score 0):

I use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to test my web services and it will give detailed statistics on size of header, payload, etc.